# Android Bluetooth Low Energy Chromebook Scanresults showing offline devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, apk, chromebook

I'm trying to get an application I created for Android to work on chromebook using the Bluetooth Low Energy feature.

My application relies on bluetooth low energy scan results, 
The scan results on my android device only shows online devices which is exactly what I need.

Sadly on chromebook devices that are offline are shown in the scanresults which causes my application to directly try to connect to a offline device...

I've also tested a chrome app "Bluetooth Scanner" this application also show offline devices in the scanresults.

My question is, how can I only show online devices that are connectable?
Is there a setting in chromebooks to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by updating the Chromebook.

Thanks to everyone who looked at this.